# Host ASP.NET ( C# 3.0 ) on Mono

Tags: mono

I have site implemented in ASP.NET ( c# 3.0). Can I host that on Mono ?
If I can, do I need to change something in my code ( except communication with database) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I host that on Mono ?

You can host your application either on Apache with [mod_mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono) or through [FastCGI](http://www.mono-project.com/FastCGI) on web servers like nginx or lighttpd.

> do I need to change something in my code

Only if some parts of your application use technologies/libraries which are not supported by mono.

Comment: Why have you said nothing about `xsp`?

Comment: Because xsp is not a web server for production use.

Answer (score 4):

Due to the [Mono Compatibility page](http://mono-project.com/Compatibility) the latest stable version of Mono (version 2.8) has complete support to the ASP.NET 4.0 and ASP.NET MVC 2. There is some useful links to read about porting and establishing your site to Mono:

- [Mono ASP.NET Section](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET)
- [Mono ASP.NET FAQ](http://mono-project.com/FAQ%3a_ASP.NET)
- [Porting ASP.NET Applications](http://mono-project.com/Guide%3a_Porting_ASP.NET_Applications)
- [Walkthrough: Porting Asp.Net MVC Website](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/02/walkthrough-porting-asp-net-mvc-website-to-mono-2-6-1-and-mysql-on-linux-apache-porting-to-mono-part-3-of-3/)